# Lebesgue Integral: Convexity

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Given a finite measure $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$.

Consider a complex function $f\in\mathcal{L}(\rho)$.

From the Riemann integral it is evident that:
$$\frac{1}{\mu(\Omega)}\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}\mu\in\overline{\langle f(\Omega)\rangle}$$

But how to prove this for the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: How do you interpret the symbol $\int_\Omega f\,d\rho$ as a Riemann integral?

Comment: It is meant to be the Lebesgue integral. From the Riemann integral it seems evident that the statement holds (for the Lebesgue integral).

Comment: But what is the Riemann integral with respect to a probability measure?

Comment: The limit of a net of the convex hull.

Comment: But how to apply this to show the corresponding statement on Lebesgue integral? I mean not every Lebesgue integrable is Riemann integrable...

Comment: That's hard to tell, since you are claiming that the Riemann integral exists with respect to any measure. I think you need to take a look at your definitions.

Comment: No statement about the Riemann integral, everything I state is w.r.t. the Lebesgue integral. *(The Riemann integral was just to have some intuition why this could hold.)*

Comment: I mean the definition I use is: $f\geq0:\quad\int f\mathrm{d}\rho:=\sup_{s\leq f}\sum_{b\in s(\Omega)}b\rho(s^{-1}b)$

Comment: Exactly. But a sup is a limit, and then you have your result.

Comment: Yep, but it's not a limit of its convex hull...

Comment: What do you mean "it's" convex hull? That you are taking convex combinations of the values of the simple functions and not of $f$? You are taking a limit, so nothing prevents you from changing the values of the functions $s$ so that they agree with actual values of $f$.

Comment: In some (please excuse me) sloppy sense, yes. But one should be careful since the limit is not only about the values but as well as about the number of summands, too. I mean similar things happen when one for example considers the uniform limit of polynomials to attain merely continuous functions rather than analytic functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K := \overline{\langle f(\Omega) \rangle}$. It is closed and convex.

Assume $c := \frac{1}{\mu(\Omega)}\int f\mathrm{d}\mu\notin K$. It is compact and convex.

Then by geometric Hahn-Banach there exists a bounded linear functional with:
$$\varphi:E\to\mathbb{R}:\quad \varphi(c)< a\leq\varphi(K)$$

But that implies:
$$a =\frac{1}{\mu(\Omega)}\int a \mathrm{d}\mu \leq \frac{1}{\mu(\Omega)}\int \varphi(f) \mathrm{d}\mu = \varphi \left(\frac{1}{\mu(\Omega)}\int f \mathrm{d}\mu\right) < a\mu(\Omega)$$
That is a contradiction!

Comment: Ui ok let me have a look. :) (And yes, the braces were meant to denote the convex hull.)

Comment: What about cases like $(a,\infty)$?

Comment: Good question. I corrected the argument (it is now simpler than before ;) ).

Comment: There's also a problem when considering complex valued functions resp. functions over complex Banach spaces as splitting functions into real and imaginary part produces queries with the convex hulls... I managed to find a proof now for the Lebesgue integral of complex functions by an approximation argument. Can you have a look on it? (Like a check for raw mistakes...)

Comment: You can just interpret every complex Banach space as a real Banach space. Likewise, the complex numbers are a real Banach space.

Comment: Yep, but the splitting into real and imaginary part does some trouble for the proof...

Comment: I don't think it does. What exactly do you think is the problem?

Comment: That in general $z\in\langle f(A)\rangle+\langle g(A)\rangle\nRightarrow z\in\langle f(A)+g(A)\rangle$ and $z\in\langle f(A)+g(A)\rangle\nRightarrow z\in\langle (f+g)(A)\rangle$.

Comment: Yes, but we do not need this here. If you have any complex vector space $V$, then $V$ is also a real vector space (just restrict the scalar multiplication $\Bbb{C} \times V\to V$ to $\Bbb{R} \times V \to V$). Let us write $V_\Bbb{R}$ for the "real" vector space. Note that $V = V_\Bbb{R}$ **as sets**. Now if $M \subset V$ is an arbitrary (nonempty) subset, then $\langle M \rangle = \{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i m_i \mid 0\leq \lambda_i, \sum_i \lambda_i = 1, m_i \in M\}$. And this is **independent** of the fact that we consider $V$ as a real or complex vector space, because all $\lambda_i$ are real.

Comment: Ah and you use sort of geometric Hahn-Banach??

Comment: Aha that was nothing but Mazur ^^

Comment: That is a pretty clever proof!! *(That goes even up to Pettis over TVS exploiting the very heart of integration - very nice!!)*

Comment: Do you mind if I shorten your answer?

Comment: I don't mind. Fell free to edit :) I will have a closer look at your answer this evening or tomorrow.

Comment: Ok I made my edits - hope it's still fine.

Comment: By the way I already gave you (+1) very nice answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the restricted, bounded case, first:
$$\Omega_N:=\{|f|\leq N\}:\quad f_N:=f\restriction_{\Omega_N}$$
*(The restriction is necessary for later reasons.)*

There exists a sequence of simple functions converging uniformly:
$$s_{N,n;k}=\sum_kb_{N,n;k}\chi_{A_{N,n;k}}:\quad\|f_N-s_{N,n}\|_\infty\to0$$

For they're Lebesgue integral one has:
$$\|\sum_kf_N(\omega\in A_{N,n;k})\rho(A_{N,n;k})-\sum_kb_{N,n;k}\rho(A_{N,n;k})\|\\\leq\|f_N-s_{N,n}\|_\infty\sum_k\rho(A_{N,n;k})=\|f_N-s_{N,n}\|_\infty\cdot\rho(\Omega_N)$$

Thus they tend to the closure of the convex hull:
$$\int_{\Omega_N}f_N\mathrm{d}\rho=\lim_n\int_{\Omega_N}s_{N,n}\mathrm{d}\rho\in\rho(\Omega_N)\overline{\langle f_N(\Omega_N)\rangle}$$
But the convex hulls agree on the restriction:
$$\langle f_N(\Omega_N)\rangle=\langle f(\Omega_N)\rangle\subseteq\langle f(\Omega)\rangle$$
*(Here, the restriction was absolutely important to identify convex hulls.)*

Now, consider the unrestricted, unbounded case.

By dominated convergence one has:
$$\int_{\Omega_N}f_N\mathrm{d}\rho=\int_\Omega f_N\mathrm{d}\rho\to\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}\rho$$
and by continuity of the measure:
$$\rho(\Omega_N)\to\rho(\Omega)=1$$

Concluding that the assertion holds:
$$\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}\rho\in\overline{\langle f(\Omega)\rangle}$$

Comment: So, you are using $s_{N,n} = \sum_k b_{N,n,k} \chi_{A_{N,n,k}}$ and you choose $f_N ( \omega \in A_{N,n,k})$ as an arbitrary element of $f_N (A_{N,n,k})$? Also, you probably want to show (or you are using implicitly) that you can take $b_{N,n,k} \in f_N (A_{N,n,k})$. The general idea you are applying should work.

Comment: Yep, I used such simple functions $s_{N,n;k}=\sum_kb\chi$ but I directly chose a point $\omega\in A_{N,n;k}$ to get $\sum_kf_N(\omega)\rho(\ldots)$ as convex combination. Ok good. Do you think I could/should simplify notation since it seems pretty messy?