# Lebesgue Integral: Differentiability

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Given a finite Borel measure $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$.

Consider an integrable function $\int|f|\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$.

Then its integral lies in the closed convex image:
$$\int_Af\mathrm{d}\mu\in\mu(A)\overline{\langle f(A)\rangle}$$
*(For more details see: [Lebesgue Integral: Convexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1013927/79762))*

Therefore the Lebesgue differentiation theorem reads:
$$\frac{1}{\mu(B_r(a))}\int_{B_r(a)}f\mathrm{d}\mu\in\overline{\langle f(B_r(a))\rangle}\stackrel{r\to0}{\to}\overline{\langle(f(a)\rangle}=f(a)$$

This seems to trivial - am I missing something?

Comment: I laughed at how much I don't know what these symbols mean.

Comment: Convex hull and topological closure ;)

Comment: The point is if you're cryptic, the probability of you obtaining a useful response is significantly diminished.

Comment: Yes, so good if people ask. ;)

Comment: The brackets are actually quite common to denote the corresponding hull operator depending on the context (convex hull, linear hull, closed hull etc.). The topological closure however is usually designated by an overlining. I changed it however so I hope its better now.

Comment: I do not see any argument in what you wrote. How do you know that the limit of the closure of the convex hull of the image under $f$ of the ball of radius $r$ around $a$ is (the closure of the convex hull of) $f(a)$?

Comment: For instance, in $\mathbb R$ you could have $f$ to be such that the image of any nontrivial interval is all of $\mathbb R$. (There are nice Borel measurable functions with this property, for instance [Conway's base-13 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function).) This $f$ wouldn't be in $L^1_{loc}$, but then you need to explain how that assumption is relevant to the computation of the limit.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: I added some details. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Hmm I see your point...

Comment: @Freeze_S No, still there is no argument in what you wrote. But yes, now you have explained some of the terms (Although I was not the one asking for clarification). You still have not discussed what kind of measure $\mu$ is, or is part of your question whether the Lebesgue differentiation theorem holds for arbitrary measures on arbitrary measure spaces? If that's the intent, then please note that as written the question makes no sense, since at least $\Omega$ needs to be a metric space, and your measure has to be a Borel measure, presumably one that is not infinite on arbitrarily small balls.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Yes, right, I corrected it. I think I see your point now. So one may have that the convex hulls do not shrink to a point: $\exists S\subseteq\mathbb{R}\forall r>0:\quad\overline{\langle f(B_r(a))\rangle}\supseteq S$

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. In essence, what the proofs of the theorem do is to argue that this ``shrinking" takes place a.e., which is why the proofs usually make use of some [covering lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ok, I guess I found the missing ingredient...*

For continuous functions one has:
$$f(B_N(a))\subseteq B_\varepsilon(f(a))$$
And therefore shrinking takes place:
$$\overline{\langle f_r(B(a))\rangle}\to0$$

Comment: $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: In general, you're right. For now, I just found some argument.